# How to set XML rules to fill certain fields using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem here that i need some help with. Look at these lines:

```
HEADING
TYPE       NAME      PBOR0    SHOP     CATREF    DETAIL    MATXT    CMPREF    BLTREF    TMPREF     PRTREF
DEFAULTS
-           -        -       =
TUBE       */Cb_N76f-RDX/T0A2013010-00:DD 0.50     TRUE  /RDX_R_AAPA1A0DD /RDX_T0A2013010-00 /RDX_VAZIO-MT   /Cb_N76f-RDX/RDX_T0A0AC0010-00:DD =0          =0          =0
```

And also these lines:

```
HEADING
TYPE       NAME      PBOR0    STYP    SHOP     CATREF    DETAIL    MATXT    CMPREF    BLTREF    TMPREF     PRTREF
DEFAULTS
-           -        -   CT      =
ELBO       */C9B0020101-00:DD 0.50     CT  TRUE  /RDX_R_ABEB360DD /C9B0020101-00  /RDX_VAZIO-MT   /Cb_N76f-RDX/RDX_C9B002AC01-00:DD =0          =0          =0
```

As you can see above, the first block is from a TUBE and the second one is from a ELBO. Both have different header columns. This problem i solved wirting a xml configuraiton like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Components>
    <Component type="TUBE">
        <Header size="11">
            <Columns>
                <Column>
                    <Name>TYPE</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>NAME</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>PBOR0</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>SHOP</Name>
                    <Defaults>=</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>CATREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>DETAIL</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>MATXT</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>CMPREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>BLTREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>TMPREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>PRTREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
            </Columns>
        </Header>
    </Component>
    <Component type="ELBO">
        <Header size="12">
            <Columns>
                <Column>
                    <Name>TYPE</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>NAME</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>PBOR0</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>STYP</Name>
                    <Defaults>CT</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>SHOP</Name>
                    <Defaults>=</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>CATREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>DETAIL</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>MATXT</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>CMPREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>BLTREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>TMPREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>PRTREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
            </Columns>
        </Header>
    </Component>
    <Component type="GASKET">
        <Header size="12">
            <Columns>
                <Column>
                    <Name>TYPE</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>NAME</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>PBOR0</Name>
                    <Defaults>-</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>STYP</Name>
                    <Defaults>RF</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>SHOP</Name>
                    <Defaults>=</Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>CATREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>DETAIL</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>MATXT</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>CMPREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>BLTREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>TMPREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Name>PRTREF</Name>
                    <Defaults></Defaults>
                </Column>
            </Columns>
        </Header>
    </Component>
</Components>
```

The problem now is: I have a lot of different rules to write values in the column, for example: To write NAME i must follow certain rules, to write STYP another, etc. Is there a simple and easy way to describe these rules in a XML, read and interpret them and write correct values according to rules in output?

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try to checkout:

- Regular Expressions
- validation with XSD schemas (I doubt that that is the case)

Probably it is not so cool answer as you expect, but anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you create classes for each type, then you would have the rules. You'd have the API for that xml to read/write with.  The advantage of classes, written in C# they are strongly typed.

Example,

```
public class Elbo
{
    XElement self;
    public Elbo(XElement elbo) { self = elbo; }

    public string Name
    {
         get { return self.Element("Name").Value; }
         set 
         { 
               XElement name = self.Element("Name");
               if(null == name)
                    self.Add(name = new XElement("Name"));
               name.Value = value;
         }
    }
}
```

Now Name is strongly typed, only a string can be written to it and read from it.  Also this is an example, you have a lot more rules (nodes) such as Column nodes etc that I skipped over.  I hope you get the point of what I wrote.

If you go with your generic approach of generic columns that can hold anything and any type, then you are going to have a lot more difficult time of developing rules to govern it all.